# How to introduce an integer function into $\zeta$ function instead of $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I have a problem that I am struggling with since long and probably it is simple but I can not get through. So your help would be very welcome.

Known that Riemann $\zeta$ function is defined as sum over positive integers $n \in \Bbb N$:

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$$

Having instead a function $\mathcal N(x)$ such that:
$$ \mathcal N(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    x & \quad \text{if $x\in \Bbb N$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right.$$

how can I formally correct introduce $\mathcal N(x)$ instead of $n$ into the $\zeta$ function formula:

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{?^s}$$

It might be just a trivial question but I can not get it?
Do I need probably instead of sum an integral?

Comment: Just write $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{{\cal N}(n)^s}$, because $n={\cal N}(n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. This is a very weird question...

Comment: @anon appreciate if you put this into an *answer* so I would quit.

Answer (score 4):

You can write it like
$$
\zeta(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{\mathcal{N}(n)^s}.
$$
Interestingly, you might be interested to know that this is reminiscent of the [Dedekind zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_zeta_function), which is defined as a sum over norms of ideals of a number field.